# How to margin-left on inline-block i want to move the whole progress bars?

Tags: html, css

hello i made some progress bars for my website .. and i want to move it on right.. note that i dont want to use `float: right;` since not works as should.. i want to move it on standard pixels on right like `margin-right` do my job but inline block cant help me, please bring me a solution to fix my problem cause iam very upset with that ! :(

example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYNoVZ?editors=110

Comment: What do you mean `but inline block cant help me`?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to move the whole progress bars on the right .. but with display:inline-block.. the progress bars does not move on right . ( check smonitor.ovh/smonitor/ )

Comment: What all of them? Right...how much? I think we need an image of what this is supposed to look like

Comment: i need it like 300px on the right ! to fit on the website.. if you check the link i send !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a parent tag (graph-container) that contains all your graphs and apply float to it as follows.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="graph-container">
    <div class="progress vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%;">
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="progress vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
  </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="progress vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
  </div>  
  </div>
   <div class="progress vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 95%;">
    </div>  
  </div>
     <div class="progress vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%;">
    </div>  
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

body {
  background-color: #1D1F20;
  //background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.graph-container{
    float: right;
}
.vertical {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 76px;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: thnx this help me lots .. ! have a good day !.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what is supposed to move any by how much but you could just add

```
.container {
  margin-top: 150px;
  text-align: right; /* this */
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black !important;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}
.vertical {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 76px;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%;">
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="progress vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
  </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="progress vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
  </div>  
  </div>
   <div class="progress vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 95%;">
    </div>  
  </div>
     <div class="progress vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%;">
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```